# DevExpress CollectionView Collapse Group problem in xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, devexpress, maui

I'm new at xamarin forms and developing an application. I make a popup page to make a menu. I'm using devexpress collectionview in it. My menu is grouped and I have 5 groups. I want collapse that groups but It doesn't work well.It works when page open first time but 2nd time it give me the error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I check the dev express documentation for xamarin forms. There is nothing about grouping but in maui part I could find some information.

https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/404126/collection-view/filter-sort-and-group-data#group-collection-view-items

OnAppearing Method :

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
            if (dxCollection.ItemCount >= 0)
            {
            dxCollection.CollapseGroup(-1);
            dxCollection.CollapseGroup(-2);
            dxCollection.CollapseGroup(-3);
            dxCollection.CollapseGroup(-4);
            dxCollection.CollapseGroup(-5);
        }
base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Visual that I want.

[image]

Error : It appears page opened 2nd time. First time is working well. What could happen that lost object and give me error. I can not find.

[image]

What could I do for debuging ? I can not find anything to controll "null" here.

DxCollectionview Group:

```
                <!--Group items.-->
            <dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupDescription >
                <dxcv:GroupDescription FieldName="ANAGRUPADI" GroupInterval="Value"/>
            </dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupDescription>
            

            <!--Define the group header template.-->
            <dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate  >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Margin="3"  >
                        <Frame CornerRadius="8" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                            <StackLayout  HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="CadetBlue" >
                                <Label FontFamily="Roboto" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                
                                <Image Source="@drawable/popupmenu.png"  HorizontalOptions="End"  HeightRequest="20" />
                                
                                
                            </StackLayout>
                            
                            
                            
                        </Frame>
                            

                        
                       
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

LayoutChildren method :

```
 protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        dxCollection.CollapseAllGroups();

        base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
    }
```

I want to add Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib but it gives error. I cant find how to add those references.
Error :

> Version conflict detected for DevExpress.XamarinForms.Core. Install/reference DevExpress.XamarinForms.Core 22.1.8-pre-23026 directly to project İdaServis.Android to resolve this issue.

> NU1202    Package Microsoft.Owin 4.2.2 is not compatible with monoandroid13.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v13.0). Package Microsoft.Owin 4.2.2 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)

Comment: Did you try to get the GroupCount when you open the page second time? And can you show the code about how did you group the item?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I checked groupcount (it comes 0 in onappearing method) but no fix and I update question with dxcollectionview group part.

Comment: Yes,  the groupcount is 0 caused the null reference exception. What's the value of it when the page first time opened?

Comment: When I open menupage for the first time DXCOLLECTION GROUP COUNT :5 but next time is 0.  @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: You can put the code into the LayoutChildren method instead of the OnAppearing method.

Comment: I'm filling those observable collection from viewmodel, is there any way after lists filled up iwth menu's collapse that groups ? I dont know LayoutChildren, I'm a new at xamarin forms. How can I add this ?

Comment: Code override in the page and you will find the LayoutChildren method. It's same as the OnAppearing method.

Comment: If I do it right still the same, first time goups are collapsed but next time not. I update question with layoutchildren method. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: If you didn't call the collapse method will all the items show when you open the page second time?

Comment: All items shown when the collapse method is comment out. This time group count comes twice as 5 then come 0 again. I can see always groups expanded without collapse method. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: I see you used `FieldName="ANAGRUPADI"`, is the `ANAGRUPADI` a property of your item?

Comment: It comes from my observable colletion. It's Name of a property. DxCollectionview group observable collection objects accourding to this property. @LiyunZhang-MSFT Anagrupadı means main group name.

Comment: It appears to be a bug. You can try to report it on the [Support Center](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/list). In addition, you can refer to the [DXCollectionView Sample](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/xamarin-forms-collection-view-examples/tree/21.1.3%2B/CS/GettingStarted/CollectionViewExample).

Comment: Thank you for your big effort @LiyunZhang-MSFT I open a ticket in devexpress page. I hope they will take care of this issue.

Comment: You are welcome. And did you open the page by the same way between first time and second time.

Comment: I tried to run their solution but ı can not succed then I decided report it. Maybe we are missing something they will tell us.

Comment: What's the solution.

Comment: I mean I download their project and try to run it.  DXCollectionView Sample. There is no solution to fix our problem.

Comment: Did you try to add a new page in the sample and open the colloectionview page multiple times?

Comment: I couldn't. It gives error like that : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\xamarin-forms-collection-view-examples-22.1.3- (1)\xamarin-forms-collection-view-examples-22.1.3-\CS\GettingStarted\CollectionViewExample.Android\obj\Debug\100\lp\78\jl\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png'.

Comment: All right, you can wait for the ticket on the support center.

Comment: Yes. It seems so.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I discover something new now. Andrey Marten (DevExpress Support) answered my question on devexpress page and he atached a project with working good as I want. Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib added his project but I can not add to my project. I add details my question.

Comment: Did you try to install the Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib lower version such as: Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib 1.7.0.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes I have tried but I got the same error again. I tried to lower verison like 1.2....

Comment: Did you install it in the android project or the share part?

Comment: I try to install in android project. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Did you try `Install/reference DevExpress.XamarinForms.Core 22.1.8-pre-23026 directly to project İdaServis.Android to resolve this issue`?

Comment: If that means the file open when double click on project name, there is a line     <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.XamarinForms.Core" Version="22.1.8-pre-23026" />  @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Yes, and you can also try to install it by the nuget package manager. But it should be install for the android part not the share project.

Comment: It doens't load anyway. I give up for now. I think I try to run with many incompatible versions together.

Comment: Yes, it seems you used many third party packages.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT  You help me a lot. Thank you very much. I'm really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome and the problem is still not resolved.

Comment: We will find a way later.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I could finally add Kotlin.Std library from nuget and make collectionview work as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I backup my project. I work on backup project.

My aim is adding Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib because DevExpress Collectionview works great with this nuget package.

Then open android.csproj file with a text editor. I used VsCode. Add those lines :

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material">
  <Version>1.6.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core">
  <Version>1.7.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

After adding these I could add Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib. But this was not enough. I fill my collectionview from my web service. Sometimes it doesn't collapse groups. Adding a delay time layoutchildren method make it great.

```
protected override async void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        await Task.Delay(250);
        dxCollection.CollapseAllGroups();

        base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
    }
```